# Hibernate mapping of hierarchy with self-join

Tags: java, hibernate

I have an interesting scenario in which I'm trying to determine a Hibernate mapping for a hierarchy of classes (need to be XML mapping files) along with the tables required.
I have a class Base which is extended by classes A, B, and C.

```
    Class Base
     |   |    |       
Class A  |  Class B
       Class C

Class Base {
   String  type;
   Double  average;
}
Class A extends Base {       
   Map<String, Integer>   aValues;
}
Class B extends Base {
   Map<String, Double>    bValues;
}
```

Q.1) There isn't any additional 'property' in classes A and B and with Hibernate the maps go to child tables. So can I map sub-classes A and B to the same table as class Base (given that hibernate-mappings of A and B include the specific collections they hold like shown below) ? I mean will a self-join/union like this be legal?:

```
<hibernate-mapping package="mypackage">
  <class name="Base" table="BASE">  
    <id name="id" column="ID">
        <generator class="assigned"/>
    </id>       
    <property name="type" />
    <property name="average" column="AVERAGE" />

    <union-subclass name="A" table="BASE">
      <map name="aValues" table="A_VALUES" cascade="all" > 
       <key column="BASE_ID" not-null="true"/>
       <map-key column="name" type="string"/>
       <element column="value" type="int"/>
      </map>        
    </union-subclass>

   <union-subclass name="B" table="BASE">
      <map name="bValues" table="B_VALUES" cascade="all" > 
        <key column="BASE_ID" not-null="true"/>
        <map-key column="name" type="string"/>
        <element column="value" type="double"/>
      </map>        
   </union-subclass> 
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

The reason I chose union-subclass instead of joined-subclass for A, B, C was to avoid having to make a reference column back to the base-class row.

Q.2) Class C is a composite holding objects of A and B.

```
Class C extends Base {
  A  aObj;
  B  bObj:
}
```

If answer to Question1 above is yes, then can Class C also be mapped to Base with the contained objects going to joined tables? Regardless, what strategy should be used to associate C to composed objects of A and B? (must I use a join with ugliness like this below?)

```
<hibernate-mapping>

  <union-subclass name="C" table="Base">    

    <join table="ASSOC" optional="true">
      <key column="parent_Id" unique="true"/>
      <many-to-one name="aObj" column="child_Id" not-null="true" unique="true"/>
    </join>     

    <join table="ASSOC" optional="true">
      <key column="parent_Id" unique="true"/>
      <many-to-one name="bObj" column="child_Id" not-null="true" unique="true"/>
    </join>     

  </union-subclass> 
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Ideally I want to use a BASE table structured like this (to map classes A,B,C and Base) instead of introducing any new (join) table:

```
Table Base
Id | Type | Average | Parent_Id
 1   Base     null      null
 2    A       10.0       4
 3    B       20.0       4
 4    C       15.0      null
```

Will appreciate any ideas/pointers.

Answer (score 0):

> The reason I chose union-subclass instead of joined-subclass for A, B, C was to avoid having to make a reference column back to the base-class row.

### Q1

If you think a A-row, a B-row and a C-row may have the same base-class-row like it would be possible in relations your thinking is wrong. Inheritance in databases works only for the structure: A-table has all the columns that have the Base-class-table has, but it has none of the rows! This means: even if A, B and C have rows, the Base-class-table may empty! The inheritance does only affect to the structure, not the data.

### Q2

Your design of class C is not composite like "all the data of A and B". Its like "all the reference to existing rows in A and B".

> can Class C also be mapped to Base with the contained objects going to joined tables?

Not joined, referenced, but yes.

> Regardless, what strategy should be used to associate C to composed objects of A and B?

No, the strategy of inherit the structure or having a `forign key` is important for the beans in hibernate. For using the inherit-way you could write something like this:

```
BaseClass patient1 = entityManager.find(A.class, 22);
BaseClass patient2 = entityManager.find(B.class, 22);
```

gives you two different rows. Using cardinailty you must:

```
C patient = entityManager.find(C.class, 22);
A a = patient.getA();
B b = patient.getB();
```

> Ideally I want to use a BASE table structured like this (to map classes A,B,C and Base)

The structure you describe is not possible using inheritance, also I can not understand what `Average` means. But to reach this structure you could map a readonly `Database View` to an entity having the restrictions that you can not update and delete the enitys for that view.

Comment: Thanks for your response. The 'average' is just a dummy property I put on the Base class.  Are you saying that I must have separate tables like A_TABLE for class A and B_TABLE for class B with foreign key in each of them referring back to the BASE table?   Even though the present design of class C does not seem composite like "all the data of A and B" but I my intention was to make it so. When I persist C, I want A and B also to be persisted (by cascade).  So If I include a mandatory foreign-key reference from C to A and B it would suffice? But then I need 4 tables.

Comment: @Don No, A and B might have same values, in 99% of the cases this is bad database design. Could you give a concrete case instead of the abstract names A,B,C?